# Jinja2 For loop variable to output sum

Tags: python, jinja2

Im trying to make a Jinja2 for loop to have a running bankroll sum from data from my mysql database.

```
{% set total = 0 | int%}
{% for row in data %}
{% if row['outcome'] == 0 %}
{% set total = total - row['stake'] | int %}
{% else %}
{% set total = total + ((row['stake'])*(row['odds'])) | int %}
{% endif %}
{{total|int}}
{% endfor %}
```

but my output on the html page is always all the numbers beside each other.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Wrap the output in a `<p>` tag: `<p>{{total|int}}</p>`

Comment: lets say i have the numbers 21 42 and -15, in my database. i want to itererate, and then get the sum of those numbers. But the output with the p tag is like this:

21
42
-15